# Generating Stats from Datagridview rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

i am working on a section of a project, that parses Logs from Postgres Database Server.
The application is developed in C sharp Framework 4.0.

A log is produced and displayed on a DataGridView with the following columns

```
resultCode       Statement                  Starttime                   Duration
XT001         select * from PizzaMade    01-02-2012 03:10:14         00:04:10
```

- there are many loglines with the sameformat.
- The Datagridview is filled from another loop by parsing a Textfile.

My work is to generate stats from the data available in Grid in the following format

```
Statement                                 Count        countpercent                    Occurs_on

select * from PizzaMade                     3             1.42        01/02 at 03pm   [00:04:10], 01/02 at 04 [00:01:04]
select id,qty,table from PizzaMade          12             5.12           ...........
```

so basically the stats reflect the following

- a) statement executed
- b) Count number of times it appears in a grid
- c) percentage of count which is basically the portion of totalcounts this statement occupies
- d) a concatenated string containing starttime,duration

---

» The stats are generated as Datatable first, using a for loop

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in LogGrid.Rows)
{
// search in the Datatable if the statement is present
// if it is then add count , add starttime and duration to the column
// if not then add a newrow

}
```

» After populating the datatable , i use a loop to calculate the Totalcount

```
int totalcount = 0;
foreach (DataRow drin StatTable.Rows)
{
totalcount = totalcount + Convert.ToInt32(dr["count"].ToString());
}
```

» After calculating the count, there is a loop to calculate the percentage

```
foreach (DataRow dr in StatTable.Rows)
{
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(dr["count"].ToString());
    dr["countpercent"] = (c/totalcount)*100;
}
```

---

Although everything seems ok, the whole method is sluggish with large number of rows.

- Can you please suggest methods to improve the performance.

thanks
arvind

Comment: You could try for getting total count to use Compute method of the DataTable, but I don't know if will increase performance

Comment: i tested the compute method on sample data of 1million records, it seems foreach loop takes 545ms and compute method 1850ms. i.e. foreach loop is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're parsing text logs it might enhance performance by operating not in grid but in objects. Also, the grid could be bound to the List of parsed logs. It could be like this:

```
public class LogItem
{
    public string ResultCode { get;set;}
    public string Statement { get;set;}
    public DateTime StartTime { get;set;}
    public TimeSpan Duration { get;set;}
}
```

Then your grid could be bound to BindingList which contains all parsed log items. While having the list, you could access data in more uniform way:

```
foreach (string statement in logItems.Select(x => x.Statement).Distinct())
{
    int count = logItems.Count(x => x.Statement == statement);
    double percentage = count / logItems.Count(); 
    // any additional data
}
```

If you'd like to be extra performant and fancy, you could save all parsed log files to database and create queries for necessary data.

Comment: i will forward this tip, but as of now i can only access what is present in the datagridview. Another method updates the Datagridview from the text file. That code is not available on my desk. Therefore this example does not present it.

Comment: can i use this Class and generate List from Datagridview rows, does that help ? Because the speed related issue to after the Rows are populated.

Comment: You can always parse the data in grid to human-like form and keep it like that :)

Comment: @arvind: sure, you could try and see if that helps. Though double-parsing is a bit awkward situation.

Comment: the double parsing system must wait, since that is a major code change

Comment: i am accepting your answer, because it does help in projecting the solution in a better way that we have implemented

Answer (score 1):

i have some suggestions,

you can use something like this to your looping process using linq. basically linq uses well optimized query which gives great performance.

```
 DataTable obj = new DataTable();
        obj.Columns.Add("count",typeof(Int32));
        DataRow dr = obj.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "10";
        obj.Rows.Add(dr);

        DataRow dr1 = obj.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = "5";
        obj.Rows.Add(dr1);

        obj.Columns.Add("countpercentage");

        int intCount = (from DataRow drrow in obj.Rows
                        select drrow.Field<int>("count")).Sum();

        (from DataRow drtemp in obj.Rows
         select drtemp).ToList<DataRow>()
         .ForEach(x => x.SetField<string>("countpercentage", ((x.Field<Int32>("count")*100) / intCount).ToString()));
```

Comment: why do we calculate average here.. (sorry but my exposure to linq is limited, )

Comment: it generates an error on 'from' keyword in both places, >> 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Comment: i have sorted out the error by adding System.Linq namespace. It produces another Error in line > int intCount = (from DataRow drrow in obj.Rows select drrow.Field<int>("count")).Sum(); < "Error : Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. " . I changed the Type from int to Long, still same error. It does sum to int type when in Foreach loop. thankx

Comment: I tried the following method , int linqSum = (from DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable()   select Convert.ToInt32(dr["Test"])).Sum(); the error is same

Comment: ok, i tried to reduce sample data from 1million rows to 10k rows and it works. But reducing rows is not a solution ? thanks

Comment: after all the processing, foreach is still fastest 481ms next is linq 1016ms and then Compute 5109ms